# Pthreads does not start more then one thread php

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

i want to use pthreads, but running the following script just prints a "1" every second, it should echo a "123" every second, it runs only the first thread.

```
<?php
require "/root/vendor/autoload.php";
set_time_limit( 0 );

function print_time( $id ) {
    while( true ) {
        print( $id );
        sleep( 1 );
    }
}


class Threaded_upload extends Thread {

    public function __construct( $args ) {
        $this->args = $args;

    }

    public function run() {
        print_time( $this->args );
    }
}

$thread_1 = new Threaded_upload( "1" );
$thread_1->start();
$thread_2 = new Threaded_upload( "2" );
$thread_2->start();
$thread_3 = new Threaded_upload( "3" );
$thread_3->start();
```

thanks for any help in advance!